# CSF Firewall - priority

Tags: firewall, csf

If a whitelisted IP (csf.allow) uses the wrong password more than 5 times, are they then automatically added to csf.deny? If so, does csf.deny OVERULE csf.allow so that they would be denied access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  csf.allow actually talks about this, and you need to add their IP to csf.ignore to prevnt it.